# Xcode Bot bitcode error during integration only

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, xcode-server, libsodium

> ld:     '/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/5c17d3e903f4d302cf453    40fb301f30f/Source/ocular/Pods/Sodium/Sodium/libsodium-  ios.a(libsodium_la-crypto_box.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7

I ran `/usr/local/bin/pod install` before integration (Triggers).

[image: screen shot 2016-08-03 at 3 18 14 pm]

I am able to build and run the app in simulator & real device. However my integration with bot failed with the above error message. I install `Sodium` via cocoapods.

I tried setting `ENBALE_BITCODE = NO` for project/targets/Pods

Server: 5.1.7
Xcode: 7.3.1

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The error saying that you need to `ENBALE_BITCODE = NO` under your project target Change that and it will gonna work.

Comment: I tried that. The solution to the problem is actually restarting my mac twice. T.T

Answer (score 1):

`xCode` -> `your project` -> `Build Settings` -> `Enable Bitcode = NO` .

Comment: I tried that. The solution to the problem is actually restarting my mac twice. T.T

Answer (score 0):

After searching for the solutions online and the only solution i can find is `Enable Bitcode = NO`. Which is what i already had!

So eventually i use the *WILD CARD SOLUTION* which is to restart `Xcode & Server` - Still throws the same error. Since there's really no solution, i restarted my mac. First time still throws errors and TADA second time it works.I have no idea what have i done to make it work or what have i not done to make it work.

PS: I `clean` and `clean build folder` each time before i integrate my bot.

To anyone who faced the same issue: good luck